# Sort Smartsheet rows with Python API

Tags: python, sorting, smartsheet-api

I'm using the Python SDK that Smartsheet provides but I'm unsure how to sort the rows. I have two date columns. I want to sort by Date1 and then by Date2 and then assign the rows in that sort order a number. I have no idea how to do this so any help would be welcomed.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is a method within the SDK that sorts the rows of a sheet, either in ascending or descending order. You'll want to update the sortCriteria -- SortCriterion array..

```
sort_specifier = smartsheet.models.SortSpecifier({
    'sort_criteria': [smartsheet.models.SortCriterion({
        'column_id': COLUMN_ID,
        'direction': 'DESCENDING'
    })]
})
sheet = smartsheet_client.Sheets.sort_sheet(COLUMN_ID, sort_specifier)
```

See here for further documentation: https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/index.html?python#sort-rows-in-sheet